# How can I deploy artifacts to Bintray using mvn deploy:deploy-file command

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, bintray

Now I use mvn deploy:deploy-file to deploy my binary files to Nexus automatically:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=temp/my-api-1.1.2.jar -DpomFile=temp/my-api-1.1.2.pom -Dfiles=temp/my-api-1.1.2-sources.jar,temp/my-api-1.1.2-javadoc.jar -Dclassifiers=sources,javadoc -Dtypes=jar,jar -Durl=https://***.com/content/repositories/releases/ -DrepositoryId=RemoteNexus --settings settings.xml
```

I don't want to use Bintray plugin for maven/gradle since my artifacts are already built and stored in my internal repository, I want to deploy to Bintray the same artifacts that I've tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two simple steps:

1. Add your Bintray repository as a server to your `settings.xml` file.
2. Use the added repository ID as the value of `-DrepositoryID=` parameter.

You can copy paste the `<server/>` tag of the `settings.xml` part from the `Set Me Up` help in your repository:
[image: Bintray Set Me Up]